# Cordova plugin overrides a default TypeScript namespace

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic2

I have installed [cordova-plugin-file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/). This is implemented like so:

```
import { File } from 'cordova-plugin-file';

constructor(file: File) { ... } 
....
```

But now I'm trying to access the Javascript [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File).

Although when I'm trying to create a normal File like so:

`let myFile = new File(blob, name, mimeType);`

The plugin name overrides the default File name which makes this option illegal.

Is there a way I can still use the javascript File and using the plugin in the same class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an alias for your import:

`import { File as FileCordova } from 'cordova-plugin-file';`

Comment: Answers should be *answers*, not questions. :-) *(I've fixed it for you.)*

Comment: not a lot of people use it, because you always keep the name from your import. But yeah you can use it and it's pretty cool.

The import function got a lot of way to handle that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

@T.J.Crowder  thanks :D